# What is the use of ResolutionEnvironment?

Tags: java, graphql-spqr

I am trying to refactor ResolutionEnvironment out so I can use that service call with @cacheable with hazelcast

I have tried reading the javadoc.
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.leangen.graphql/spqr/0.9.7/io/leangen/graphql/execution/ResolutionEnvironment.html

It doesn't tell me much.

I tried System.out.println when I do a service call.  It does show some things but the details are not clear.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.